# Method For Constructing Self Referential Formulas Like Tupper's

Tags: computational-geometry, graphing-functions, mathematica, computational-mathematics

Can anyone please explain exactly how formulas like [Tupper's self referential formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tupper%27s_self-referential_formula) can be constructed?

I'll like to see the reasoning behind the derivation of such formulas and the steps required to create a new one.

NOTE:
I know [Tupper's self referential formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tupper%27s_self-referential_formula) is [not as 'self referential' as it is claimed](https://shreevatsa.wordpress.com/2011/04/12/how-does-tuppers-self-referential-formula-work/) but some form of 'universal' formula capable of producing any bitmap of a given size, given the value of N.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The formula can produce any 17 bit high image.  The secret of finding the self-referential image is in the constant $k$, essentially knowing where to look.  How to determine $k$ is given in the article you link to:  "The constant k is a simple monochrome bitmap image of the formula treated as a binary number and multiplied by 17. If k is divided by 17, the least significant bit encodes the top right corner; the 17 least significant bits encode the rightmost column of pixels; the next 17 least significant bits encode the 2nd rightmost column, and so on."  Just take the image you want, express it in binary, and you have $k$.

Comment: I'm already aware of that. I want to know how the formula was derived. Thanks anyway!